# Creating a large dictionary in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am trying to solve the following problem using pyspark. 
I have a file on hdfs in the format which is a dump of lookup table.

```
key1, value1
key2, value2
...
```

I want to load this into python dictionary in pyspark and use it for some other purpose. So I tried to do:

```
table = {}
def populateDict(line):
    (k,v) = line.split(",", 1)
    table[k] = v

kvfile = sc.textFile("pathtofile")
kvfile.foreach(populateDict)
```

I found that table variable is not modified. So, is there a way to create a large inmemory hashtable in spark?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`foreach` is a distributed computation so you can't expect it to modify a datasctructure  only visible in the driver. What you want is.

```
kv.map(line => { line.split(" ") match { 
    case Array(k,v) => (k,v)
    case _ => ("","")
}.collectAsMap()
```

This is in scala but you get the idea, the important function is `collectAsMap()` which returns a map to the driver.

If you're data is very large you can use a PairRDD as a map. First map to pairs

```
    kv.map(line => { line.split(" ") match { 
        case Array(k,v) => (k,v)
        case _ => ("","")
    }
```

then you can access with `rdd.lookup("key")` which returns a sequence of values associated with the key, though this definitely will not be as efficient as other distributed KV stores, as spark isn't really built for that.

Comment: Cool thanks. Does this mean that map has to fit in the memory of the driver? Or is it still distributed?

Comment: @Kamal yeah it has to fit in mem. U could use pair rdd as a lookup table. Also thought of a solution with accumulable, will post soon

Comment: Okay. I was looking for a distributed map in spark. Looks like it is not possible!

Comment: aren't you missing a } ?

Answer (score 1):

For efficiency, see: [sortByKey() and lookup()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html)

> lookup(key):
>
> Return the list of values in the RDD for key key. This operation is done efficiently if the RDD has a known partitioner by only searching the partition that the key maps to.

The RDD will be re-partitioned by sortByKey() ([see: OrderedRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/OrderedRDDFunctions.html)) and efficiently searched during `lookup()` calls. In code, something like,

```
kvfile = sc.textFile("pathtofile")
sorted_kv = kvfile.flatMap(lambda x: x.split("," , 1)).sortByKey()

sorted_kv.lookup('key1').take(10)
```

will do the trick both as an RDD and efficiently.