# Spark: Fastest way to look up an element in an RDD

Tags: performance, scala, apache-spark

I have a custom class E which has, among others, a field `word`. I have a large `es: RDD[E]` with several 100000 elements and a `doc: Seq[String]` with typically a few hundred entries. In `es`, every element's `word` field value is unique.

My task is to look up the element in `es` for each of the strings in `doc`. It is however not guaranteed that such an element exists. My naive Scala/Spark implementation is thus:

```
def word2E(words: Seq[String]): Seq[E] = {
  words.map(lookupWord(_, es))
    .filter(_.isDefined)
    .map(_.get)
}
```

The method `lookupWord()` is defined as follows:

```
def lookupWord(w: String, es: RDD[E]): Option[E] = {
  val lookup = es.filter(_.word.equals(w))

  if (lookup.isEmpty) None
  else Some(lookup.first)
}
```

When I look at the Spark stages overview, it seems like `lookupWord()` is a bottleneck. In particular, the `isEmpty()` calls in `lookupWord` take relatively long (up to 2s) in some cases.

I have already persisted the `es` RDD. Is there any other leverage for optimizing such a task or is this just as good as it gets when operating on such a dataset?

I have noticed the `lookup()` method in `PairRDDFunctions` and considered to construct a PairRDD in which the `word` field would serve as the key. Might that help?
Drawing any conclusions experimentally here is quite hard because there are so many factors involved.

Comment: you could try an indexed RDD  - refer to  accepted answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724786/distributed-map-in-scala-spark

Comment: IndexedRDD do look like addressing my exact task. However, they are not yet available in the most recent Spark release (1.4.1 as of writing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is that you trigger for each word in `words` a complete traversal of your `RDD` and then collect the elements. One way to solve your problem is to join the sequence of words with your `RDD`:

```scala
case class E(word: String, value: Int)

object App {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test").setMaster("local[4]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

    val entries = sc.parallelize(List(E("a", 1), E("b", 2), E("c", 3), E("c", 3)))

    val words = Seq("a", "a", "c")

    val wordsRDD = sc.parallelize(words).map(x => (x, x))

    val matchingEntries = entries
      .map(x => (x.word, x))
      .join(wordsRDD)
      .map{
        case (_, (entry, _)) => entry
      }
      .collect

    println(matchingEntries.mkString("\n"))
  }
}
```

The output is

```
E(a,1)
E(a,1)
E(c,3)
E(c,3)
```

Comment: This looks promising, although I need to have a mapping between input strings and `E` elements; not a straight mapping though, but if two equals strings are contained in `doc`, the matching `E` should occur twice in the result sequence; this might be doable by emulating a multimap, I suppose.

Comment: @Carsten, did I understand you correctly, that you're actually looking for a join operation? Thus, if `words=Seq("a", "a", "c")` you wanna have the output `Seq(E("a", 1), E("a", 1), E("c", 3), E("c", 3))`?

Comment: @Carsten, I've updated my answer with a join solution.

Comment: That answer indeed did the trick, the performance is now definitely significantly faster. I also tried the solution I briefly sketched initially, creating a `PairRDD` and use its `lookup()` method: also significantly faster, but much slower than using `join()` (although making objective comparisons remains quite hard).

Comment: You could also try to use a broadcast join since the `words` sequence is quite small. See here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17690254/4815083

Comment: One more question: in the line `val wordsRDD = sc.parallelize(words).map(x => (x, x))`, why would you set the 2nd element to `x`? I understand that it is discarded after the join operation. Couldn't you save memory and write `map(x => (x, null))` instead?

Comment: @Carsten, you're right. It's not necessary and setting the value to `null` should save some space :-)