# What is the alternative and faster way to look up an element in an RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, lookup

I am new in Scala and Spark. This is a simple example of my whole code:

```
package trouble.something

import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object Stack {
  def ExFunc2(looku: RDD[(Int, List[(Double, Int)])], ke: Int): Seq[List[(Double, Int)]] = {
    val y: Seq[List[(Double, Int)]] = looku.lookup(ke)
    val g = y.map{x =>
      x
      /* some functions here
      .
      .
       */
    }
    g
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("toy")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val pi: RDD[(Int, List[(Double, Int)])] = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, List((9.0, 3), (7.0, 2))), (2, List((7.0, 1), (1.0, 3))), (3, List((1.0, 2), (9.0, 1)))))
    val res = ExFunc2(pi, 1)
    println(res)
  }
}
```

I am running a large enough data, and I need faster performance. By looking at Spark's web UI and a software profiler. The most consuming time is `lookup()` function:

```
 val y: Seq[List[(Double, Int)]] = looku.lookup(ke)
```

What is an alternative and way to lookup an element in an RDD rather than `lookup()` function?

There is a discussion related to this problem [Spark: Fastest way to look up an element in an RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32221960/spark-fastest-way-to-look-up-an-element-in-an-rdd). However, it does not give me any idea.

Answer (score 3):

You should not have performance issues with the lookup function if you use and scale it carefully.

> `def lookup(key: K): Seq[V]`
>
> Return the list of values in the RDD for key key. This operation is done efficiently if the RDD has a known partitioner by only searching the partition that the key maps to.

By default functions which generate a PairRdd use the HashPartitioner. So check what your `spark.default.parallelism` value is set to, since this is the number of partitions that the [HashPartitioner will default to](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-rdd-partitions.html). You can tune that parameter to match the `# of executors * # of cores per executor` you are using.

You should confirm that your PairRdd does in fact have a known partitioner, and if it does not, use `partitionBy` to create one, or modify your existing code to use a HashPartitioner when the PairRdd is created.

`let parallelismFactor = # of executors * # of cores per executor`

Then if the lookup function is still too slow, you will need to increase the `parallelismFactor` you are using. Now spark will know which partition to lookup in, and as you increase the `parallelismFactor`, you will reduce the size of each partition, which will increase the speed of the lookup.

Keep in mind that you may wish to have many times more partitions then `executors * cores`, you will have to benchmark your use case yourself, trying values from 1-10 times more partitions then `executors * cores`.